# Golang `go get` - Cannot find package in any of

Tags: go, installation, failed-installation

I've followed [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-go-1-6-on-ubuntu-16-04) to install Go on Ubuntu 16.04. However, when I follow the [installation instructions](https://github.com/src-d/enry#installation) for a Go application (`go get github.com/src-d/enry/cmd/enry`), I get the following error:

```
package github.com/src-d/enry/v2: cannot find package "github.com/src-d/enry/v2" in any of:
        /usr/local/go/src/github.com/src-d/enry/v2 (from $GOROOT)
        /root/work/src/github.com/src-d/enry/v2 (from $GOPATH)
package github.com/src-d/enry/v2/data: cannot find package "github.com/src-d/enry/v2/data" in any of:
        /usr/local/go/src/github.com/src-d/enry/v2/data (from $GOROOT)
        /root/work/src/github.com/src-d/enry/v2/data (from $GOPATH)
```

Here's the output of `go env`:

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/root/work"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT="1"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Note: I have absolutely zero knowledge of how to program in Go, I'm just trying to install a CLI application.

Comment: That looks like it might be a module import path, but you're using GOPATH. Try setting `GO111MODULE=on`.

Comment: @JimB after running `export GO111MODULE="on"`, I still get the same error. `echo $GO111MODULE` does return `on`

Comment: Follow the official way to install Go as found on golang.org.

Comment: @APixelVisuals Could you please share your import statements?

Comment: your gopath is on `/root` are you sure it's read/writeable by `go get`?

Comment: @APixelVisuals: `GO111MODULE` shouldn't be needed anyway, since this is a `main` package and your CWD is inn't in `GOPATH`. Are you using the current version of Go?

Comment: @JimB I'm using Go 1.6

Comment: @ardhitama I'm logged in as root so this shouldn't be a problem

Comment: @APixelVisuals: go1.6 is very old and hasn't be supported in a few years. You will need go1.12 to build this package.

Comment: @JimB Looks like the guide I was following was outdated. Installing the newest version did fix it. Feel free to turn this into an answer. Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

Check the writable right of $GOPATH. As you setting, it at /root

Comment: I'm logged in as root so this wouldn't be an issue

Comment: @APixelVisuals: in general, you should never be building software as root (with the exception of root in a namespaced container of some sort)

Comment: @APixelVisuals why doesn't try to do that as a normal user?